# How to efficiently search and delete in a repeated object type of Google protobuf?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am new to protobuf. I need some help with search and deletion operations.
I have a .proto file defined like this

```
syntax ="proto3";

package emp_db;
message employee
{
int32 EMP_ID =1;
string NAME =2;
string DOB  =3;
string IMG_ADD =4;


}

message employees{
repeated employee person = 1;

}
```

I can add person profile to the employees msg in a sort of array like fashion. But I can't find the necessary functions to search and delete elements of person object of employees message. After parsing through the internet, I understood there no straight way to delete the object except to swap it with last element and remove the last element. However, I am finding it difficult in finding the necessary api's. Can anyone provide a small snippet?

Thank you

Comment: Objects generated by protobuf should not participate in any business logic of application. So no searching there! Those object should be used just to serialize and deserialize some data.

Comment: Yeah, I understood it is primarily used for transmission via wire. I was originally looking for a C++ alternative for python library pickle and ended up with this. @Marek R